# Is it possible to use a Jar stored in AWS or Simple web server to Android Studio ?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio

Is it possible to use a Jar stored in AWS or in Simple web server to Android Studio or java. ?

Comment: I didn't do such things, but I think it's possible in theory: you can create custom dependency resolver, which will go to AWS and find your jars.

Comment: @slesh So, Breaking Jar and calling classes or Objects from server can be done..?? Actually I didn't find anything related in Internet, and I'm trying to implement something like this...

Comment: I think it's possible with gradle to create dependency loader that will load your jars/.class/files from AWS, put them to either .gradle/cashes or libs and add them to classpath. As I said I have not experience with it, but I have read about gradle abilities and it seems it is possible to implement.